# Закомментирование папки для GitHub через GIT

Tags: git, github, git-commit

При попытке добавить папку в репозиторий на GitHub'е и вводе команды $ git add . выскакивает такие строки: 
$ git add .
fatal: LF would be replaced by CRLF in css/slick-theme.css
Как это исправить

Comment: Вы каким редактором пользуетесь? Означенный файл написан вручную или чем-то собран?

Comment: Пользуюсь ST 3.
Данный файл был кем-то собран и скачан мною. Но если добавлять по каталогу, то пишет такую же ошибку с первого добавленного файла.

Comment: То есть, по сути, этот файл не редактируется никем, просто лежит в репозитории? ...ну, должен лежать.

Comment: да, сейчас этот файл лежит у меня на ПК, но почему-то не папка не добавляется в репозиторий GIT.

Comment: Вроде закомментировало .